# Chapter subtitle

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, chapters

I want a chapter subtitle (half the size of the font of the chapter title) within the rulers of the chapter title. The subtitle must not appear in the Table of Contents. I have this

```
\makechapterstyle{mychapterstyle}{%
    \renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries}%
    \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries}%
    \renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}%
    \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]  {%
        \chaptitlefont\hrule height 0.5pt \vspace{1em}%
        {##1}\vspace{1em}\hrule height 0.5pt%
        }% 
    \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{%
        \chapnumfont\thechapter%
        }%
}
\chapterstyle{mychapterstyle}
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\sffamily\bfseries}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}
\setparaheadstyle{\normalfont\sffamily}
\makeevenhead{headings}{\thepage}{}{\small\slshape\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{headings}{\small\slshape\rightmark}{}{\thepage}
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest might be to double the argument to `\chapter` by using both the (optional) ToC-entry as well as the (mandatory) sectional heading, removing the sub-heading from the former. Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\makechapterstyle{mychapterstyle}{%
    \renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries}%
    \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries}%
    \renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}%
    \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]  {%
        \chaptitlefont\hrule height 0.5pt \vspace{1em}%
        {##1}\vspace{1em}\hrule height 0.5pt%
        }% 
    \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{%
        \chapnumfont\thechapter%
        }%
}
\newcommand{\chapsubhead}[1]{%
  \\{\normalsize #1}%
}
\chapterstyle{mychapterstyle}
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\sffamily\bfseries}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}
\setparaheadstyle{\normalfont\sffamily}
\makeevenhead{headings}{\thepage}{}{\small\slshape\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{headings}{\small\slshape\rightmark}{}{\thepage}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*
\chapter[This is a chapter]% ToC entry
  {This is a chapter \chapsubhead{This is a sub-heading for this chapter}}

\end{document}​
```

The newly defined `\chapsubhead` inserts a forced line break, and groups the sub heading to localize any font changes (currently set to `\normalsize`). You could define a new macro like `\chapsubheadfont` that you can redefine however you want to. But it would seem that one would need a consistent formatting across your document, and therefore a macro containing this as-is should suffice.

The alternative might be to open the bowels of the `\chapter` setting and insert a subhead. An interface would have to be created or done similar to the `\maketitle` command of [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) where a definition is removed after it's used. This is what I mean by such a user interface:

```
\setchaptersubhead{This is a sub-heading for this chapter}
\chapter{This is a chapter}
```

where `\chapter` would remove any definition set by `\setchaptersubhead` once the chapter heading is complete (so it doesn't spill over to subsequent chapters). Although it can be done, this might be sufficient for your usage.

Comment: If carefull one can also overload `\chapter` to take an extra optional but braced option using the `xparse` package.